# Adding object to array in Vue

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I'm having trouble adding an object into an array.

this is the the script I'm using:

```
<script>
export default {
  name: 'pokemon',
  data(){
    return{
      pokemon: [
        {name: "Bulbasaur", number: "001"},{name: "Ivysaur", number: "002"},{name: "Venusaur", number: "003"},
        {name: "Charmander", number: "004"},{name: "Charmeleon", number: "005"},{name: "Charizard", number: "006"},
        {name: "Squirtle", number: "007"},{name: "Wartortle", number: "008"},{name: "Blastoise", number: "009"},
        {name: "Pikachu", number: "025"}, {name: "Mewtwo", number: "150"}
      ],
      selected:'',
      seen: false
    }
  },
  methods: {
    addPokemon(){
        var name = document.getElementById('pokeName').value;
        var number = document.getElementById('pokeNum').value;
        var pokeSON = "{name: \"" + name + "\", number: \"" + number + "\"}";

        this.pokemon.push(pokeSON);
    }
  },
}

</script>
```

and I'm pulling the name and number from:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Pokémon Name" id="pokeName">
<input type="number" placeholder="3 digit Poké Number" id="pokeNum">
<button v-on:click="addPokemon">Add Pokémon</button>
```

When I click on the button, it adds an undefined object to my list. Any ideas to point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to push an actual object, not a string.

```js
addPokemon(){
        var name = document.getElementById('pokeName').value;
        var number = document.getElementById('pokeNum').value;
        var pokeSON = {name: name, number: number};

        this.pokemon.push(pokeSON);
    }
```

Comment: That was simple. Thank you very much!